# Use Datediff with update query.An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement

Tags: c#, sql, datetime

I am using this query to update Hours according to two datetime values"

```
UPDATE CheckInCheckOut 
SET CountHours=ROUND(SUM(DATEDIFF(ss,'2014-05-15 00:23:04.580',
'2014-05-15 00:25:04.580') / 60.0 / 60.0), 2) 
FROM CheckInCheckOut
```

Here CountHours is decimal(18,0)

DateDiff workes if I use select but gives error on update..?

Any example would be appreciated.

Comment: `SET CountHours=SELECT...`

Comment: that worked. It is always 0 hours. if I remove one /60.0 then it gives minute as 2. How to show it as 0.3333 in CountHours ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem:

You are adding `from CheckInCheckOut` at the end of the UPDATE statement.

try this:

```
update CheckInCheckOut 
set CountHours=ROUND(SUM(DATEDIFF(ss,'2014-05-15 00:23:04.580','2014-05-15 00:25:04.580')  / 60.0 / 60.0), 2)
```

Here is UPDATE syntax:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value1,column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value;
```